# Extension method to loop through enums and run a generic action

Tags: c#, generics, foreach, enums, extension-methods

There are quite many places in my code where I need to loop through enum values to do something. So for the sake of simplicity and clarity, I would like to convert, for example, the following piece of code

```
foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(myEnum)))
{
    chart1.Series[$"Series{name}*"].Enabled = optParams[(myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), name)];
}
```

into

```
typeof(myEnum).ForEach((name, value) =>
{
    chart1.Series[$"Series{name}*"].Enabled = optParams[value];
});
```

I have tried this extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this T t, Action<string, T> action) where T : Enum
{
    foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
    {
        action(value, (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name));
    }
}
```

But when I call it as above, the compiler cannot recognize `e` and so throws this error: `CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'myEnum'`.

If I change the way I call it—this time to explicitly specify the type of T (***twice?***)—to

```
typeof(myEnum).ForEach<myEnum>((name, value) =>
{
    chart1.Series[$"Series{name}*"].Enabled = optParams[value];
});
```

then the error will change to `CS1929   'Type' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'…`.

How can I fix this?

***UPDATE:***
Putting @Tim's suggestion forward, I changed my extension method to

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this Type t, Action<string, T> action) where T : Enum
{
    foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
    {
        action(value, (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name));
    }
}
```

And it works like

```
typeof(myEnum).ForEach<myEnum>((name, value) =>
{
    chart1.Series[$"Series{name}*"].Enabled = optParams[value];
});
```

The problem, however, as @Olivier pointed out, is that I have never used `t` in my extension method. The extension method can be written as

```
public static void ForEach2<T>(this Type t, Action<string, T> action) where T : Enum
{
    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(t))
    {
        action(Enum.GetName(t, value), (T)value);
    }
}
```

but still have to be called in the format of `typeof(myEnum).ForEach<myEnum>()`.

***UPDATE2***:

As @Olivier clarified, an extension method was not necessary here as it is not intended to call it upon an instance of an enum, and so it could be done using an ordinary `static` method like below.

```
public static class Enums
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(Action<string, T> action) where T : Enum
    {
        foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
        {
            action(value, (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name));
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
Enums.ForEach<myEnum>((name, value) => {…});
```

Comment: It seems you want to extend `System.Type` not enum

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Preferably also a dotnetfiddle.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thanks, yes, if I change my extension method to `ForEach<T>(this Type t, Action<string, T> action) ...`, it will be fixed, but I still need to call it like `typeof(myEnum).ForEach<myEnum>(...)`. Am I specifying the type twice now? I mean, could I simplify the call method further to `typeof(myEnum).ForEach()`?

Comment: You can't call the method on an *Enum type* using it as `this` that is an instance of an object... not a type. You don't need generic here. Simply write or refactor: `foreach ( EnumType value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)) )`. I hope this can help you to enjoy C# coding: [How do I improve my knowledge in C#](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm)

Comment: @OlivierRogier, could you clarify how to achieve this without a generic extension?

Comment: @Mehdi Simple foreach or refactor. You can't use a type as an instance... You can't write `MyEnum.ForEach()`. `Enum` is a special sealed system "pseudo-"class. You can't use that type or any type as an instance of an object of type of a class or a struct or anything else.

Comment: Found these duplicates having a generic foreach refactored as well as .NET 5 `Enum.GetValues<T>()` sample : [Foreach on enum types in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361635/foreach-on-enum-types-in-template) & [How to enumerate an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum). No extension method is possible because extension methods need an instance, not a type.

Comment: @OlivierRogier, Thanks for the links, but the first link is suggesting a generic method, and the second link is a huge step backwards...

Comment: @OlivierRogier, my code is working now as I explained in my comment to @Tim. My only remaining question is if there's a way to call it like `typeof(myEnum).ForEach()` not `typeof(myEnum).ForEach<myEnum>(...)`—again, this last one is working.

Comment: @Mehdi You never use `t` because of what I wrote. The use of such an extension method is not clean and is anti-pattern, anti-OOP. Create a simple method from the duplicate in an `EnumHelper` class for example, which you call like this: `EnumHelper.ForEach<myEnum>(action);` and all is well. Also you can put this static class any extension methods relevant to enums instance like `Next<T>(this ...)` and `Previous<T>(this ...)` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642542/how-to-get-next-or-previous-enum-value-in-c-sharp (here you can use extension methods).

Comment: @OlivierRogier, thanks again, I updated the question to kind of reflect your ***true*** comment on never using `t` in my extension method.

Comment: @OlivierRogier, updated again to reflect your solution as shown in Update 2. Please post it separately and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, you can do what you are trying to do by standing on your head (and making sure that your two type specifications line up; you probably want to throw an exception in your extension method if `typeof(T)` doesn't match `t`).

The problem is that you can't create a static extension method.  You can only call an extension method on an instance.  So, for example, I can do the following:

```
public static void Foreach<T>(this T anEnum, Action<string, T> action) where T : struct, Enum
{
    foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
    {
        Enum.TryParse<T>(name, out var val);
        action(name, val);
    }
}
```

but, I can only call it on an instance of my enumerated type, not on the type name itself.  So, for example, this works:

```
public enum ATestEnum
{
    A,
    Test,
    Enum
}
```

Followed by this code:

```
ATestEnum.Test.Foreach((name, val) => Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {name}, Value: {val}"));
```

but, with the kludge that you can't call it on `ATestEnum`, you have to call it on an instance of `ATestEnum` (in this case `ATestEnum.Test`).  This is kludgey, since it acts on all instances of the enumerated type.  Such is life.